# Mysql/Eloquent: How to count many-to-many relationsship

Tags: mysql, eloquent, relation

There are 3 main tables:

`preferences` with fields `id` and `code`

`user_preferences` with fields `user_id`, `preference_id` and `value`

and table `users` by itself

My question is how to count by how many users is each preference is turned on. The main problem is that preference should be counted as turned on in two cases:

1. If `value` in `user_preferences` is `true`
2. If there is no record for preference in `user_preferences` (by default it means true)

So, for example if there are

`users` (1_user, 2_user)

`preferences` (1_pref, 2_pref)

`user_preferences` (1_user -> 2_pref -> false)

the result should be 1_pref = 2 and 2_pref = 1

Answer (score 0):

The db schema looks wrong. The value field is not needed and redundant. If user has a preference then there will be an entry user_preferences else there will be no record.

Suppose I have two records in user_preferences with same user_id and preference_id. For first record, value is true and for second record value is false. What does this mean, does the user have that preference or not. This shows the db schema is incorrect.